# C# Post Web API

Tags: c#, post

I want to do a HTTP Post request in C# but I just don't know how to do that. I have tried a lot of methods online but it threw different errors.

Essentially I want to do a post request to this api:

```
http://localhost:57772/api/user/
```

I can do this in postman with:

```
http://localhost:57772/api/user/?name=Paul
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
             {
                 { "name", $"{activity.From.Name}" },
             };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:57772/api/user/", content);
```

And the error is:

> 405 method not allowed

Here is my controller:

```
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return users;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(string name)
    {
        var user = users.FirstOrDefault((n) => n.name == name);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(user);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult PostNewUser(string name)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Invalid data.");
        var user = new User { name = name, message = "Hello3" };

        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, "stop the chat");

        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can do it already in postman what is the problem?  Are you trying to make a POST request or receive one?

Comment: Pick some code that you found, try it out, post what you did and the error you got and then we'll be able to help.

Comment: You need to add more details. What errors you encounter? Postman request looks like a GET and not POST.

Comment: I want to do it using c#

Comment: @Sunil Just add the detials. Thanks

Comment: As I said, the Postman request looks like a GET request. Does your API support [HttpPost] attribute? From the error it looks like it doesn't

Comment: @Sunil I use the POST request in postman. And it does support that.

Comment: `?name=Paul` is associated with GET, not POST, like @Sunil says.  Can we see your controller method, including the signature?

Comment: @JimW I just put my controller on. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this one:

```
string url = "http://stopbyte.com"; // Just a sample url
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.QueryString.Add("parameter1", "Hello world");
wc.QueryString.Add("parameter2", "www.stopbyte.com");
wc.QueryString.Add("parameter3", "parameter 3 value.");

var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", wc.QueryString);

// data here is optional, in case we recieve any string data back from the POST request.
var responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

from [How to send Parameters Data using WebClient POST request in C#](https://stopbyte.com/t/how-to-send-parameters-data-using-webclient-post-request-in-c/79/3)

And thanks to the people who questions whether I am using POST or GET being so helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     byte[] response = client.UploadData(“http://localhost:57772/api/user”, new NameValueCollection()
     {
           {“name”, “Paul”}
     });
}
```